# How to create a new index in Elasticsearch 5 from .Net or NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

I am trying to create a new Elastic 5 index from .net and data from a SQL database into it using the bulk API.

I have created a POCO for mapping:

```
using Nest;

namespace NEST5
{
  [ElasticsearchType(IdProperty = "data_id")]
  public class Test_Data
  {    
     public int data_id { get; set; }
     public string address { get; set; }
     public string location { get; set; }
  }
}
```

And I am getting the data from SQL into a list of type Test_Data

Then I am trying to connect to my Elasticsearch server and create an index:

```
var connectionPool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://<ip here>:9200/"));
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool, new InMemoryConnection())
 .DefaultIndex("test_data")
 .BasicAuthentication("username", "password");

var client = new ElasticLowLevelClient(settings);

var descriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor("test_data")
 .Mappings(ms => ms
 .Map<Test_Data>(m => m.AutoMap())
 );

client.IndicesCreate<Test_Data>("test_data", descriptor, null);
```

However, this does not show an error, but is not creating a new index as required either.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `new InMemoryConnection()` in your `ConnectionSettings`, try removing that.

Comment: Is it not possible to search data held in memory with elastic?